# Are question about removing another OS but Ubuntu on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Title says it all. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/175873/169736) inspired this meta-Q. So, are questions about removing another OS but Ubuntu on-topic?

Relevant comments:

> mint is offtopic on askubuntu. But you can format the partition with mint on it with gparted. FOr the remainder: mount the partitions and you can c/p data. –  Rinzwind
>
> @Rinzwind while Mint is off-topic, I don't believe this question truly is. the OP wants to remove Mint(and maybe Windows as well) and keep Ubuntu. If a question about removing another OS and keeping Ubuntu is really off-topic, there are a lot of questions on askubutu about removing Windows and keeping Ubuntu that are off-topic as well..... –  TrailRider Aug 15 '12 at 0:21

BTW, I edited the tags/title to be easier to search, but I still think that there should another dupe.

If you haven't noticed this Q doesn't need TLDR!

Relevant: [Is this the right place to ask a question about installing another OS on an Ubuntu computer?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3043/is-this-the-right-place-to-ask-a-question-about-installing-another-os-on-an-ubun)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, this and all such questions are be on-topic because it is a part of administration on Ubuntu and all questions related to administration on Ubuntu are on-topic. Quoting the [help-center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic):

> We welcome questions about:
>
> - Using and administering Ubuntu, including official Ubuntu derivatives.
> - Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
> - Development on Ubuntu.
> - Services provided by Ubuntu
> - Any question not mentioned below or here are great! There are no "dumb" questions!

Removing an OS using Ubuntu is absolutely related to Ubuntu, in fact, it may be a fundamental operation while installing Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score -2):

IMHO If the machine has Ubuntu(not compulsory) in it and/or the question states it(that removing has anything to do with Ubuntu or another os(es) that are multi-boot with Ubuntu :=> compulsory) then it's definitely NOT-OFF TOPIC [Also the question should be about resolving within Ubuntu unless it is removing Ubuntu using another OS]

Answer (score -2):

The question you link is clearly off topic. It is about about Mint and GRUB, not directly related to Ubuntu in any way. It would fit better at the [Linux/Unix site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).